# Different Aop proxy created for same object when using setTarget and ProxyFactory(Object target) method

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Here is the code

```
//IUserService is a interface
IUserService userService=new UserServiceImpl();

NameMatchMethodPointcut pointcut=new NameMatchMethodPointcut();
pointcut.addMethodName("save*");


LogAdvice logAdvice=new LogAdvice();


Advisor advisor=new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut,logAdvice);

//when set the target in constructor JdkDynamicAopProxy will be created
//ProxyFactory proxyFactory=new ProxyFactory(userService);
ProxyFactory proxyFactory=new ProxyFactory();
proxyFactory.addAdvisor(advisor);
//if use setTarget to set the target ObjenesisCglibAopProxy will be created
proxyFactory.setTarget(userService);

IUserService proxy=(IUserService) proxyFactory.getProxy();

proxy.queryUser();
proxy.saveUser();
```

And the difference between set target using `setTarget` or in `Constructor` is that when in `Constructor` there is `setInterfaces(ClassUtils.getAllInterfaces(target));` but not in `setTarget`, i don't know why, as i think since `IUserService` is a interface, `JdkDynamicAopProxy` should be created no matter how i set the target?
The spring source code version is `5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: When using `setTarget` it is asummed that you configure everything manually (so you need to call `setInterfaces` as well). When using the constructor this is implied.

Comment: @M.Deinum Get it